# Can igniteFS be used with Ceph?

Tags: hdfs, ignite, ceph

IgniteFS can be used on top of HDFS. However, Ceph also provides support for HDFS http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/cephfs/hadoop/.

Is it possible to use IgniteFS on top of Ceph to speed file access?

Answer (score 0):

IGFS can be setup on top of any Hadoop-compliant file system provided that infrastructure around this file system doesn't rely on any proprietary API and works only through standard FileSystem API.

Comment: have you or anybody else has ever tried it in production?